# Setting variables in shell script by running commands

Tags: shell, unix

```
>cat /tmp/list1
john
jack

>cat /tmp/list2
smith
taylor
```

It is guaranteed that list1 and list2 will have equal number of lines.

```
    f(){
        i=1
        while read line
          do
        var1 = `sed -n '$ip' /tmp/list1`
        var2 = `sed -n '$ip' /tmp/list2`
        echo $i,$var1,$var2
        i=`expr $i+1`
            echo $i,$var1,$var2
          done < $INFILE
    }
```

So output of f() should be:

```
1,john,smith
2,jack,taylor
```

But getting

```
1,p,p
1+1,p,p
```

If i replace following:

```
var1 = `sed -n '$ip' /tmp/list1`
var2 = `sed -n '$ip' /tmp/list2`
```

with this:

```
var1=`head -$i /tmp/vip_list|tail -1`
var2=`head -$i /tmp/lb_list|tail -1`
```

Then output:

```
1,john,smith
1,john,smith
```

Comment: Most shells of the Borne family also accept the notation i=$(( $i + 1 )) for calculations and $(command) for execution. I find this much nicer... besides you can nest them in ways the execution quotes do not allow or makes things clearer to most readers. x="$( foo "$bar" $(( $i + 1 )) )";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use paste and awk command, you can achieve the same with a one-liner:

```
paste -d, /tmp/list1 /tmp/list2 | awk '{print NR "," $0}'
```

Replace the while script with this line :)

Answer (score 2):

the $ip is the problem there making ip the name of the variable, you should use ${i}p instead letting the shell know that the variable is i not ip, your code should look like

var1=`sed -n "${i}p" /tmp/list1`

var2=`sed -n "${i}p" /tmp/list2`

Comment: How is this supposed to work with the spaces around the `=` and the substitution-inhibiting single quotes around $i?

Comment: edited with double quotes and no spaces, I'm new here and find it hard to type right in this thing, first 3 tries everything was in a single line